# Cardinal numbers

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Suppose $m, n$ are infinite ordinal numbers.
$$a) m=n → |m|=|n|$$
$$b)|m|=|n| →m=n$$
$$c)m<n→ |m|<|n|$$
$$d)|\max{(m,n)}|< |m|+|n|$$
$$e)|m|<|n| →|m|^{|n|}<|n|^m$$

Which of the above statements are true? (a) looks true but I do not know the way to work it out. Please help

Comment: What is your definition of *cardinal*?

Comment: Number of elements in a set

Comment: That's not a definition. That's an informal explanation of what is a cardinal number. How do you define $|\Bbb R|$?

Comment: That doesn’t help. If $m$ is a cardinal, what’s the difference between $m$ and $|m|$?

Comment: $|R|=c$. I know each equivalence class is called a cardinal number

Comment: @BrianM.Scott even I could not understand the difference between m and |m|. This question was taken out of an examination paper

Comment: That doesn't help. If $|m|$ an equivalence class of sets? Is it an ordinal? Is it something else? What is $||m||$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila These were the only information that was given at an examination paper. No information was ommitted

Comment: There’s no way to answer the question unless you can find out just what definition of *cardinal number* the person who composed that exam paper expected you to use. If nothing more was said on the paper, the person who composed it must have expected students to know a particular definition.

Comment: No one is sending out exams to arbitrary people. If you are looking at this exam then you should have studied some course, some material, **something**. And in that something you should find the definition of a cardinal number which will then tell you what the answer should be.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I eddited my question hoping that it would make more sense.

Comment: Your question becomes a really peculiar now. Some of these questions make sense when asking about ordinals, but others don't. Did you change this only because your definition of cardinals is that they are ordinals? Or did you change that because the question now says "ordinals" instead? Also note that the last statement has somewhat of a typographical inconsistency with the powers on the RHS.

Comment: I hope that after the edit the question makes more sense

Comment: The last one doesn't add up. There are counterexamples, but in order to fully understand them you need to know enough set theory that the other statements become really trivial to solve.

Comment: Before I'm getting into writing n answer. Do you know what an ordinal number is? Do you know what is a successor ordinal, and what is a limit ordinal?

Comment: Yes I do know them

Comment: In the future, please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be closed, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Recall that $|x|=|y|$ is an equivalence relation.
2. Recall that $|\Bbb N|=|\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}|$, so adding or removing one element does not change the cardinality. You said that you know what is a successor ordinal, this should give you a counterexample.
3. The counterexample to the previous statement should give you a counterexample to this one as well.
4. Recall that addition of cardinals satisfy $|a|+|b|=\max\{|a|,|b|\}$.
5. Consider $\omega$ and $\frak c$ (as suggested by Chris Eagle in the comments).

Comment: For (e), just take $\aleph_0<2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @Chris: You're right. I was thinking about equality, rather than reversing the inequality sign.