# Statements regarding ordinal numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Let $m$ and $n$ be infinite ordinal numbers

Which of the following is true

a) $m<n \Rightarrow |m|^{|m|}<n^{|n|}$

b) $m+n$= Max{$m,n$}

c) $m=n \Rightarrow |m|=|n|$

d)$|m|=|n| \Rightarrow m=n $

e)  Max{$m,n$} <$|m|+|n|$

I could only understand that d) is false due to the cardinality of the two different ordinals can be the same and c is true! Please help on the rest of the statements

Comment: When you write $+$ or exponentation of cardinals, do you mean the *ordinal* or the *cardinal* operations?

Comment: Possible duplicate : [Cardinal numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/433580/53976)

Comment: @tetori: Not really. Two of the five parts are the same, but the other three are only similar.

Comment: If you are the same user as Rajinda Wickrama, it is better to use only one account rather than asking the same question from a different account. If you want to ask about just one part, it is better to write an entirely new question focusing on that part instead of duplicating the old one.

Comment: Also, please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be closed, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one?).

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming ordinal operations) For a) note that $\omega < \omega + 1$, and as $\omega^n \le (\omega + 1)^n < \omega^\omega$ holds for all $n$, we have $$\omega^\omega = \sup_n \omega^n \le \sup_n (\omega + 1)^n = (\omega + 1)^\omega \le \omega^\omega$$
so $(\omega + 1)^\omega = \omega^\omega$, showing that a) is wrong.

For b) note that $\omega + \omega = \omega2 > \omega = \max\{\omega, \omega\}$.

For e) finally the strict inequality needn't hold in general, as one can see for example from 
$$ \omega_1 = \max\{\omega, \omega_1 \} = \omega + \omega_1 $$

Comment: @CameronBuie No, part (a) posits that $|m|^{|m|} < n^{|n|}$.

Comment: Oops! Right you are.